# Where can I find information on the Pentax Q lenses serial protocol?

Tags: lens, autofocus, pentax

I'm searching for detailed information on the Pentax Q lenses (any, but I'm especially interested in the 5-15mm-lens) serial protocol, which controls focus/zoom/aperture.

So far I have found nothing on the internet regarding the protocol and I'm thinking I will have to examine the data transfer between lens and camera body myself, to get the information.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've found and why it didn’t meet your needs.  
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why someone flagged this as off-topic due to being about _video_. This is a regular still camera line.

Comment: That said, "where can I find...?" is generally off topic, as opposed to just asking the question directly....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about DIY hardware development.

Comment: The obvious place would be Pentax.  These things can be considered proprietary, but with coaxing and perhaps agreeing to an NDA they might help.  Worth a try.  Make clear why you want to know (and if it's for commercial purposes or not).

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult search. I found a lot of information on the Canon EF mount (largely because of Magic Lantern), and some about Nikon. Pentax is not enough of a mainstream brand to interest a lot of folks to reverse engineer the lens-camera communication, and the Pentax-Q is even a smaller subset of that. I noticed that on the Metabones FAQ page, they say, "We do not have complete specifications of the respective mount communication protocols...", so that means either they are made available to them or they reverse-engineered them. I'd recommend that you email Metabones to see if they 1) know what the specification is, or 2) know how to obtain it, and 3) would divulge it to you, and then I would also email Pentax (Ricoh) to see if they would be willing to would divulge the specifications.